# How do I align Box shadow to the Center of the screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Please whats the best way to make a box shadow appear in the center of the screen? Sought thru and I have not found anything that can be of some form of assistance in that Light.
My css I have written looks like the given below:

```
  .paypalPayment{
    width: 700px;
    height: 52px;
    margin:59px;
    position:absolute;
    border:2px solid #fff;
    background: url(pp2.png) no-repeat;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #ccc;
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #ccc;
    -khtml-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #ccc;
  }
```

And this has been put inside the div which should display the Boxshadow in the HTML area.
I just want it to be centered. How do I go about something like this?

**Edits**

The Box-Shadow rather than comes to the center of the Screen, goes to the Left start of the page.
Now that is the css class that is supposed to align the css, I tried using `align-items: center;` turns it never worked out.

My code for the Html looks thus :

```
import React from 'react';
import './app-styles.css';
import Vector from './Vector.png'
import ie_logo from './ie_logo.png';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';


function HomePage() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <header className="header">
        <img src={Vector} style={{margin:7, flexDirection:'column', alignItems: 'center'}} alt="Vector" />
        <img src={ie_logo} style={{margin:7, flexDirection: 'row', width:114, height:25}} alt="ie_logo" />
        <p className="needhelpText">NEED HELP?</p>
        </header>
            <form>
                <div className="InstructionText">
                    payment
                </div>

                <div className="paypalPayment" >
                </div>
            </form>
        <footer className="footer">
        <a href="#" className="footerLinks"> Privacy Policy | &nbsp; </a>
        <a href="#" className="footerLinks">Do Not Sell My Personal Information | &nbsp; </a>
        <a href="#" className="footerLinks">Advertising Guidelines | &nbsp;</a>   
        <a href="#" className="footerLinks">Site Map  &nbsp;</a>  

        <div className="copyrightText">
        © Copyright 2021 | Luther Corp | All Rights Reserved
        </div>
        <div className="footerLogo"> 
        <img src={ie_logo}  alt="ie_logo" />
        </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
  );
}

export default HomePage;
```

This is my CSS

```
.header{
    background-color: #007FC0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 25px 0;
}

.container{
    flex : 1 1 auto;
    color:white;
}

.needhelpText{
    text-align: right;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 22px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    float: right;
    font-family:'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    font-size: medium;
}

.copyrightText{
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}

.footerLinks{
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}

.footerLogo{
    float: right;
    display:flex;   
    margin-right: 17px;
    margin-left: 22px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 114px;
    height : 30px;
}

.footer{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #16192C;
}

.InstructionText {
    margin-bottom: auto;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 35px;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #007FC0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight:bolder;
    display: flex;
  }
  
  .InstructionText:after {
    content: "";
    border-bottom: 4px solid #FF9900;
    width: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    width: 549px; 
  }

  .paypalPayment{
    width: 700px;
    height: 52px;
    margin:59px;
    align-items: center;
    position:absolute;
    border:2px solid #fff;
    background: url(pp2.png) no-repeat;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #ccc;
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #ccc;
    -khtml-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #ccc;
  }
```

The CSS responsible for doing that is with the class `paypalPayment`

So please How do i go about pushing the boxshadow to the center?

**Edits 2**

Sofar I think I have gotten it to center. Now it chunks against each other. And looks like this now

[image: 12.png]

How do I in turn space it? I am kind of new to CSS

Comment: `best way...` question will lead to an opinion-based anwser and are a reason to close questions. However, if you seek help you gotta provide more details and clarity. Make a minimal reproduicable code snippet. just providing text where less then 50% contain a vital information and css-code lines not going to help us understand the case.

Comment: Please See Edits

Comment: what edits? there are none. And frankly it will impossible for us to tell you how to move a box shadow to the center of the screen not knowing how the site structure (espacially HTML) is like.

Comment: @tacoshy, i edited the question

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by `How do I in turn space it?`

Comment: My bad. How do i create a space between that area Payment and the box-shadow @Hashir

Comment: You can simply increase the height of the class `.paypalPayment` or set the `height: auto` so it auto increase when you add content to it.

Comment: @Evans You want to center the div with the shadow, right? But where should the Paypal logo be? In this div or not?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's what you want to do

**CSS file**

```
/* HEADER */
header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #007fc0;
  padding: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.header-logo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.needhelpText {
  display: block;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: white;
}

/* MAIN */
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 25px;
}
.InstructionText {
  margin-bottom: auto;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 35px;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #007fc0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bolder;
  display: flex;
}
.InstructionText:after {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 4px solid #ff9900;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  width: 450px;
}
.paypalPayment {
  height: 52px;
  width: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background: url("https://i.postimg.cc/qRBnhQhh/paypal-2.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: 85px;
  background-position-y: center;
  background-position-x: 10px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgb(177, 177, 177);
}

/* FOOTER */
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #16192c;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.footerLinks {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 0;
}
.footerLinks li a::after {
  content: "|";
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.footerLinks li:last-child a::after {
  content: "";
  margin: 0;
}
.footerLinks li a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
}
.copyrightText {
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
}
.footerLogo img {
  width: 30px;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

**HomePage.js**

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      <header>
        <div className="header-logo">
          <img src={vector} style={{width: "250px", height: "auto"}} alt="Vector" />
          <img src={ie_logo} style={{width: "114px", height: "auto"}} alt="ie_logo" />
        </div>
        <div className="needhelpText">NEED HELP?</div>
      </header>

      <main>
        <form>
          <div className="InstructionText">payment</div>
          <div className="paypalPayment" />
        </form>
      </main>

      <footer>
        <ul className="footerLinks">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Do Not Sell My Personal Information</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Advertising Guidelines</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Site Map</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div className="copyrightText">
          © Copyright 2021 | Luther Corp | All Rights Reserved
        </div>
        <div className="footerLogo">
          <img src={ie_logo} alt="ie_logo" />
        </div>
      </footer>
    </div>
```

Demo: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nj2yty?file=src%2FApp.js)